# asp.Net website: improve google page speed insights

Tags: asp.net, pagespeed, core-web-vitals

To improve Google scores I know some services like NitroPack, available for CMS like Wordpress or Magento. However I have a site developed in Asp.Net that I don't want to rebuild with another CMS. Are there solutions similar to NitroPack compatible with Asp.Net?

Comment: ...why not just go through the Google performance report's line-items and address them one-by-one? (I avoid any service or library that promises to improve performance like that, it's often snakeoil...)

Comment: I didn't develop the site myself. I am not familiar with asp.net and would rather not touch it.

Comment: So... you want some kind of _magic solution_ that will just-work but doesn't require you to do anything at your end?

Comment: Yes, as I wrote. I'm wondering if there is a NitroPack-like service that supports Asp.Net...